# Ubuntu 20.04 stuck with no signal to monitor

Tags: 20.04

Ubuntu 20.04 worked normally on the first day, but on the second day, there was no signal on the monitor. After restarting, it gets stuck in the user selection interface. Moreover, the external mouse and keyboard failed, and the monitor lost signal again after staying on the user selection interface for a while.

Comment: Might want to make sure that your mouse and keyboard are set to legacy mode in your BIOS.  You might need to also do a power reset on your system.  Power off the computer, if a laptop unplug from power and remove battery if possible.  If a tower, unplug from power.  Then press and hold in the power button for 30 seconds.  Plug all power back in and reboot the computer.